# Instances of a form

Tags: vb.net

I got a problem and I'm a little confused, so I'm just going to put it simple:

I have 2 forms (form1 and form2).

Form1 has a tabcontrol which shows form2 in a tabpage. 
Form2 has a button1 that closed itself and therefore the tabpage.

I'm using this code for button1:

```
Dim f1 As New Form1()
f1.tabControl1.Controls.Remove(f1.tabControl1.Selectedtab)
```

Using the above code I got an exception so just to be sure that the tabpage is there i add this in button1 before removing the tabpage:

```
Console.Writeline(f1.tabControl1.TabCount)
```

Using the instance shows 0. But using the default instance shows 1:

```
Console.Writeline(Form1.tabControl1.TabCount)
```

I want to know if I'm doing something wrong creating an instance

Pd: I know I can use this:

```
Form1.tabControl1.Controls.Remove(Form1.tabControl1.Selectedtab)
```

But I need to work with instance

Edit:

I got a NullReferenceException when i use:

```
Dim f1 As New Form1()
f1.tabControl1.Controls.Remove(f1.tabControl1.Selectedtab)
```

As i said, it works if i use the deafult instance

Edit 2:

This is the code i use to create the tabpage, this method is in form1 and i call it in a click event of a button in form1:

```
Dim tabpage1 as new Tabpage
Dim f2 as new Form2

tabpage1.Controls.Add(f2)
f2.show()

tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabpage1)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the exception. Please add it to your question. If you remove the SelectedTab from your f1-instance then its expected that it has one tab less than the default instance.

Comment: Yes, but i'm doing the Console.writeline before removing the tabpage, so both, the isntance and the default instance, should have one tabpage the .tabcount only shows 1 for the default instance

Comment: I can't reproduce it anyway. I've created an empty Form, added a TabControl with one Tab and created an instance of the form. It shows TabCount=1 without a `NullReferenceException`. There must be something inside your Form1-Class which is causing this.

Comment: Could it be that i'm adding the tabpage programmatically ?

Comment: @D Torres I think that's the problem. You'll need to call the method in which you're creating the Tabpage, before querying `f1.tabControl1.TabCount`

Comment: You never show your form, so the load event never happens.

Comment: My bad, i call the method in the click event of a button in form1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer:
In form2:

```
Dim f1 As New Form1
Public Sub New(ByRef _f1)
' TODO: Complete member initialization 
InitializeComponent()
f1 = _f1
End Sub
```

I just had to reference form1